# Since upgrade to 22.04 I encounter regular "held back" at apt upgrade

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade

I have some installs of *buntu on different machines that have been upgraded for several years. With all of them I experience rather regular (e.g. once a fortnight) "held back" packages at my weekly (dist-)upgrade; and only since 22.04. Never seen this since 8.04 or so; that is during the last 15 years.

I have seen some questions for SPECIFIC packages. I still decided to ask once more; as a GENERAL question, since I have multiple installs, and all behave the same in this respect. I do know to handle this situation.

Since we are in "AskUbuntu", I think this is a perfect place to ask if I am the only one; and what the underlying reason could be.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yiou don't have to do anything. Unless it bothers you, why not let the Ubuntu package manager hande this. 

If you know that you want these held back upogrades you have a few choices: 

1) sudo apt-get dist-upgrade 

2) You can install each one specifically. 
sudo apt-get install <package>

Comment: I know how to work around, thanks.
My question was in principle answered by the link to the 'phased updates'. Thanks anyway!